# Can I validate an azure-pipelines.yml file via CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml

I'm trying to build an azure-pipelines.yml for a monorepo, and I'm struggling to figure out how to debug the file as I move along.

Is there a command such as `az deployment validate ./azure-pipelines.yml` available?

If so, how do you recommend I go about doing this?  I keep making changes, pushing them to my repo, and then letting Azure DevOps run it, and fail.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

no, there is no way to validate it. when you try to run it - it will show you the error, thats the only real way to validate it.

this VSCode extension provides syntax highlighting and autocompletion.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azure-devops.azure-pipelines

Comment: I added this extension and it works nicely for my top level .yml file.  However, I am using a mono-repo and have mulitple .yml files.  But, overall, I appreciate the extension.  Thank you!

Comment: ok, that doesnt really change anything? or is that extension only capable of working with the default filename? i didnt yet use it

Comment: It’s complaining about missing pieces in my sub-pipeline files.  I have a main pipeline that calls out templates for the subrepos, and then those sub repos call out build.yml files.  For the subrepo templates, it’s complaining that things are missing, unaware that it’s being called from a parent yml file.

Comment: I'm doing something like this: https://github.com/jayway/monorepo-azure-pipeline (my repo is owned by my company, so I can't publish it)

Comment: yeah, i dont really see a problem with templating, you got some questions on that?

Comment: the VSCode extension is complaining about my azure-pipelines.yml files in my subrepos, but they work fine in my DevOps pipeline on Azure.

Comment: The point of my question is that I should be able to validate it without running it.  What if running it involves taking resources up and down, or publishing my repo.  It’d be nice to know what is going to happen without actually making it happen.

Comment: Issue tracking this request: https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/issues/34

Comment: They closed that request without actually adding support for includes/multiple files : (

Comment: @4c74356b41 F1 -> Change Language Mode -> Azure Pipelines
Or press bottom right language mode button on status bar and choose Azure Pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

There is now a Visual Studio Code extension which provides the ability to validate your pipeline YAML code before commiting it to your repo.

The extension is called [Azure Pipelines YAML Validator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomAustin.azure-devops-yaml-pipeline-validator&ssr=false#overview). The author explictly states that it uses an online service for validation, i.e. your pipeline will be uploaded for inspection. So you have to trust the author that your data is handled with care and you should ensure that no sensitive data like secrects are stored in your pipeline code (it's a bad habit anyway).

### Option 2

There is also a new PowerShell cmdlet introduced by this [pull request](https://github.com/MethodsAndPractices/vsteam/pull/272): [Test-VSTeamYamlPipeline](https://methodsandpractices.github.io/vsteam-docs/docs/modules/vsteam/commands/Test-VSTeamYamlPipeline#test-vsteamyamlpipeline). To use that cmdlet for validation you will need to install the PowerShell module `VSTeam` (PowerShell 5.0+ or PS Core required):

```
Install-Module -Name VSTeam -Scope CurrentUser
```

Next you need to specify your Azure DevOps project:

```
Set-VSTeamAccount -Account <Name of your Azure DevOps org> -PersonalAccessToken <Your PAT with access to your project>
```

(There are also options to connect to self-hosted Azure DevOps servers - see [docs](https://methodsandpractices.github.io/vsteam-docs/docs/modules/vsteam/commands/Set-VSTeamAccount).) Your PAT must have at least the permission 'Build: read & execute'.

Then you are able to validate **changes** made locally against an already set up pipeline. That means you must have created a pipeline, based on a committed YAML file, before. For validation you will need the *project name* and *pipeline ID*. To get these information open your pipeline in Azure DevOps and extract the information from the URL:

```
https://dev.azure.com/<DEVOPS_ORG>/<PROJECT_NAME/_build?definitionId=<PIPELINE_ID>
```

The validation request will look like this

```
Test-VSTeamYamlPipeline -Project <PROJECT_NAME> -PipelineId <PIPELINE_ID> -FilePath '<PATH_TO_YAML_FILE>'
```

If you have syntax errors then you get an output indicating the error:

> Test-VSTeamYamlPipeline: /your-pipeline.yml (Line: 12, Col: 13): Unexpected value ''

If everything is ok the output is a bit cryptic and looks like this for me:

```
Name url                                                                                                      state   Id
---- ---                                                                                                      -----   --
     https://dev.azure.com/<DEVOPS_ORG>/<SOME_GUID>/_apis/pipelines/<PIPELINE_ID>/runs/-1 unknown -1
```